# Access static variables by their names

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, ref

I'm working on some Unity C# scripts.

```
public class SomeClass {    
     public static float radius;
}
```

I have a `class` with a lot of `static` variables (I know `static` variables may be a bad practice, but I'm not the one who implemented those `static` variables and I need to use them).

In another script I need to change the value of those variables.
So I access them using `SomeClass.radius = val` but I want to access them using their names:

```
SomeFunction(string name) { theVariableCorespondingToTheName = val }
```

This seems trivial but can't figure out how to make it work (I'm new to C#). Do I need a function that returns the ref of the variable in my `class` containing my `static` fields?

Comment: Use a single `Dictionary<string, float>` instead. Then add values like `dict.Add("radius", defaultValue)`. Later you can update them via `dict[name] = val;`.

Comment: Didn't saw your post thanks i will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, a design with lots of statics can be improved. However, it appears that you have no direct control over it, so here is a way to use reflection to accomplish what you need:

```
typeof(SomeClass).GetField("radius").SetValue(null, val);
```

Comment: Are you using reflection in your code regularly? Mostly unexperienced users ask for reflection because they don't know other ways to solve their requirement. So in most cases these are XY-problems.

Comment: For portable libraries it looks slightly different but close enough to guess.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It looks like OP wants a work-around to deal with someone else's code. He is not looking for a design advice.

Comment: Thanks, yes i'm working on someone else's code and i can't change it too much (the design is not perfect unfortunately). I think i will use reflexion for the moment and try to implement a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you really cannot change the design, you have to use reflection. However, then the compiler will no longer know that all the fields are typed as floats and you will get a lot of boilerplate code and lose a lot of performance.
The exact syntax for Reflection are different according to the .NET version you are using.

The much better solution if you were allowed to change the fields would be to create a single `Dictionary<string, float>` as suggested by Tim Schmelter in the comments.